# Upload image from Camera or Gallery

Tags: ionic4

I am using Ionic 4. While I upload an image from the Camera or Gallery, I'm getting a Type Script error.

I have tried the following code :

```
chooseImage() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionSheet.create({
        title: 'Choose Picture Source',
        buttons: [{
                text: 'Gallery',
                icon: 'albums',
                handler: () => {
                    this.actionHandler(1);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Camera',
                icon: 'camera',
                handler: () => {
                    this.actionHandler(2);
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
}
```

Comment: can you add the error

Comment: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function is error

Comment: @satheesh There's nothing in your code to handle uploading a file. Please post all of the code that pertains to the question along with the full error in your question, not as a comment here.